# mysql to get last three month data from month name column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table name mis. Having two column month and qtd.
Month column type is varchar(250). From this column I wish to get last three month data.

```html
My mis table look like.
month    qtd
=================
January  12
February 32
March    10
April    34
May  76
June     44
July     12
```

```html
Output:-
month   qtd
May     76
June    44
July    12
```

Comment: _“Month column type is varchar(250)”_ - why?

Comment: _“From this column I wish to get last three month data.”_ - we are not Santa Claus, so please show what you have already tried, to make this “wish” of yours come true.

Comment: CBroe Thanks for the reply. This is the query which i have tried.SELECT * FROM mis where month = MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(month, '%M')-INTERVAL 3 MONTH)

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE(month, '%M')-INTERVAL 3 MONTH` results in `NULL` already, no matter what month name you put in there.

Comment: Monthname only cannot be converted to correct date value using STR_TO_DATE(). Add fake year and day number to it.

Comment: And what happens at the end of a year. Does your table wrap-around. In other words: Do you need the results for "November" and "December" the next year?

Comment: @Ben, Yes i also need the results for "November" and "December" the next year.

Comment: Next january - will this insert new january row, or update the existing one? The column should not be month name, but a date, then you can order by it and just take 3 last rows. There also isn't any ID column? If there is you could just SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3. You can also try naive approach. In PHP get names of 3 months that interest you (current month: month1, previous :month2 and one before that month3) and make a query: SELECT * FROM t WHERE month = :month1 OR month = :month2 OR month = :month3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
SELECT *
FROM mis
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(mis.`month`, ' 01 2020'),'%M %d %Y'), "%m") DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Thanks Atul.This is what exactly i am looking